# I have to make a unit test for methods which use connectionstrings. Is it possbile to use Entity Framework to help me test connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have to make a unit test for this and it makes me go insane because i don't know how i should do this without connecting to the database.This isn't code i made  myself but the code form a member of my group.

```cs
public IActionResult FamilyDoctor()
{
    List<Patient> GetPatientData()
    {
        List<Patient> PatientDataArray = new List<Patient>();

        Connection conn = new Connection();
        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(conn.getConnectionString());
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM measurement;";
            cmd.Prepare();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                int ID = reader.GetInt32("id");
                decimal bloodsugar = reader.GetDecimal("bloodsugar");
                decimal bloodsugardesired = reader.GetDecimal("bloodsugardesired");
                string description = reader.GetString("description");
                DateTime time = reader.GetDateTime("time");
                //int status = reader.GetInt16("status");

                PatientDataArray.Add(new Patient(ID, bloodsugar, bloodsugardesired, description, time));

            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
            }

            return PatientDataArray;
        }

        ViewData["Patient"] = GetPatientData();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t make a unit test that connects to a database. You can make an integration test, though. Which part of the method are you supposed to be testing?

Comment: Oh and you might want to mention to the other team member that the command and data reader objects should be disposed as well as the connection, and that `using` statements are the usual way to do this.

Comment: While you’re at it, suggest they don’t use `SELECT * FROM` but instead reference the columns they want in the `SELECT` statement

Comment: Oh and finally - the code that gets the data should be separate from the code that returns the View.

Comment: The shown code does not look like it has anything to do with entity framework. This code should be refactored to use the data abstractions and should also not be tightly coupled to the `Connection` implementation concern

Comment: They want me to check the return of view and patientdataray. intergration tests are also not a option because when i proposed it they didn't want to use it.

Comment: then ask "them" to pick up a modern book about software development, or switch team...

Answer (score 3):

Code like that cannot be unit tested, only integration tested with a known data state. EF won't help you.  To write unit-testable code you need to start enforcing separation of concerns and inversion of control. For example, a repository pattern can help by wrapping the data retrieval so that business logic can received a dependency to the repository, which a unit test can mock. Whether that repository uses EF or ADO is of no consequence to the code being tested.

That said, the above code you have posted doesn't have any business logic, it is simply returning all patient data from the database. Unit tests are geared towards testing business logic that will do something based on data that is retrieved.  However, what you might use as a most basic example in place of the above code:

```
public class PatientRepository : IPatientRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Patient> GetAllPatients()
    {
        List<Patient> PatientDataArray = new List<Patient>();

        Connection conn = new Connection();
        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(conn.getConnectionString());
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM measurement;";
            cmd.Prepare();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ID = reader.GetInt32("id");
                decimal bloodsugar = reader.GetDecimal("bloodsugar");
                decimal bloodsugardesired = reader.GetDecimal("bloodsugardesired");
                string description = reader.GetString("description");
                DateTime time = reader.GetDateTime("time");

                PatientDataArray.Add(new Patient(ID, bloodsugar, bloodsugardesired, description, time));
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           if (connection != null)
               connection.Close();
       }

       return PatientDataArray;
}
```

then in the controller:

```
public PatientController(IPatientRepository patientRepository)
{
    this.PatientRepository = patientRepository;
}

public IActionResult FamilyDoctor()
{
     ViewData["Patient"] = PatientRepository.GetAllPatients();
     return View();
}
```

As you can probably tell, this is somewhat pointless to test, but the view is test-able without a database as the PatientRepository can be mocked and set up to return a known data state, or throw an exception, etc. without needing a database connection. If the controller was checking the patient data, or transforming it, that logic can be tested based on a known state.  You don't unit test the repository code, it's just fetching data. You unit test behaviour, and in this case, there really is no behaviour.

This can help make the code test-able, but with or without the repository it's not particularly efficient. Your data access method is doing a `SELECT *` from the database to populate a model. Entity Framework and a unit of work pattern can help make this a lot more efficient, while still easy to test.

For instance, you define an entity to reflect the complete Measurement, and related records from your system. Using the repository pattern, you return an `IQueryable` of your entities which your calling code under test can consume.

The controller defines the unit of work which serves as the container for the DbContext. (Think of the DbContext like the Connection)

```
public PatientController(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory, IPatientRepository patientRepository)
{
    this.UnitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
    this.PatientRepository = patientRepository;
}

public IActionResult FamilyDoctor()
{
    using(var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
        var measurements = PatientRepository.GetAllMeasurements(unitOfWork);
        var viewModels = measurements.Select(x => new MeasurementViewModel
        {
            ID = x.Id,
            BloodSugar = x.BloodSugar,
            BloodSugarDesired = x.BloodSugarDesired,
            Description = x.Description,
            Time = x.Time
        }).ToList();

     ViewData["Patient"] = viewModels;
     return View();
}
```

Now the unit of work factory / pattern above is just a stub example. You can search up various examples of where/how a unit of work pattern can be implemented. The purpose of the UoW is to wrap the DbContext. It serves as a facade around EF's DBContext making it easier to substitute with a mock to test.

Where the measurement repository using EF looks more like:

```
public IQueryable<Measurement> GetAllMeasurements(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    return unitOfWork.Context.Measurements.AsQueryable();
}
```

Note: The `AsQueryable()` is needed if you just want to return the `IQueryable` for the `DbSet` as a whole. Any filtering you apply with `Where` conditions will return `IQueryable` automatically. In many cases you will have low level rules for your data, such as things like maybe an IsActive state to reflect measurements for patients that are active, not deleted/hidden. The repository can enforce these base level rules so that you don't need to remember to check them everywhere:

```
public IQueryable<Patient> GetAllPatients(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    return unitOfWork.Context.Measurements.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Patient.IsActive);
}
```

This would return only active measurements for active patients. For more scenario-specific criteria you can add methods or arguments to calls to have the repository apply additional filtering, but I prefer to simply let the consumer apply specific criteria as needed. It keeps the repositories more simple & lightweight and easier to mock out.

What does this give us?

By returning `IQueryable<Measurement>` we allow the consumers of the repository to choose what data they want, or what they want to do with that data. In the above case, by selecting just the 5 fields, the SQL that gets executed would just select those 5 columns, not `SELECT *`. Any `Where` conditions we apply will be translated into the SQL leading to faster queries. If we just want a `Count`, or an exists check with `Any`, these will result in far better performing queries than selecting all data back to check for these.

The code is far simpler to unit test as our test fixture can construct a mock of the IUnitOfWorkFactory and the Repository, where the repository mock simply returns a list or array of made-up Patient objects as `.AsQueryable()` for the logic to consume.

Again, a case where you just want to get a set of data from the database and spit out to a view doesn't really get any value from a unit test. It's simply not doing anything. However, where you have code that wants to perform an action where it will be retrieving data and making a decision about what to do, or whether to do something based on the data returned, re-factoring code to break out the data retrieval from that business logic, and leveraging EF to efficiently query that data will become a whole lot more useful and easier to test.

The next thing would be to look at how you return data. Unit tests are well suited to assert the results of behaviour via checking return values and asserting mocks. Using ASP.Net specific structures like `ViewData` makes it hard to test. Returning `View(viewModels)` would be a little easier. Generally I would recommend either designing pages to load data asynchronously where the "View" methods don't take a populated model, and instead render empty and kick off a data load using GET calls that return `JSon()` as the ActionResult, or hand off to a service which returns the collection of applicable data where the controller merely wraps that data. In that last case you unit test the services, not the controller.

So, with that in mind, can you take the existing code and unit test it? No, not really. But this should give you some ammunition to go back to the rest of the team and say that if they want to have code covered by unit tests, this is the kind of re-factoring they should apply to make it happen. Unit testing is something that has to be accommodated up-front. It can be hard to introduce late in the development process if the project has not made use of test-friendly patterns like IoC/DI.